# How to I add recipients to this macro that sends an email?

Tags: excel, vba

This macro sends an email to person1, but not to person2 (with  a comma separating.) Have tried many different ways to add multiple new addresses.

Any input appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Sub sendEmail()
    
    ' this sends an email
       
       Worksheets("REPORT").Activate
       
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
    
        Set rng = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
    
        Set rng = Sheets("REPORT").Range("A1:AF51").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "theres nothing here" & _
                       vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
    
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .ScreenUpdating = False
                End With
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = "person1@gmail.com", "person2@gmail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Temporary CrossCut: Sawmill Report"
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
    
                With Application
                    .EnableEvents = True
                    .ScreenUpdating = True
                End With
    
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        
        Worksheets("REPORT").Activate
        
        Range("A1").Select
    
        Range("A1").Activate
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Set the emails to a variable and use that. Also use a ; between the emails.

Comment: `.To = "person1@gmail.com; person2@gmail.com"`